# Adding checkboxes to jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am new to JQuery. 
Can anyone tell me how to add checkboxes to a jquery dataTable?

Comment: I have tried adding the following to aoColumns but it’s not working:
{
  type: 'checkbox',
  checkbox: {trueValue: 'Yes', falseValue: 'No'
}
Please help.

Comment: aoColumns = [
{"sName":"myCol1","mRender": function (data,type,full) {
  return '<input data-id="' + full[0] + '" type="checkbox">';
}
]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess you're using the jQuery [datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin here:

You can use the [`aoColumnDefs`](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns) parameter to customize a column, like-

```
aoColumnDefs  : [
{
    aTargets: [0],    // Column number which needs to be modified
    fnRender: function (o, v) {   // o, v contains the object and value for the column
        return '<input type="checkbox" id="someCheckbox" name="someCheckbox" />';
    },
    sClass: 'tableCell'    // Optional - class to be applied to this table cell
}]
```

Comment: fnRender was deprecated! use mRender / mData. See http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

Comment: Thanks Vishal...